Force TLS 1.2 Connections at my API hosted on Heroku
I have one NodeJS based API hosted on Heroku using the Hobby Dyno (Paid plan) and it works normally.
One client said that he can only uses APIs that follows the TLS v1.2 (something about Java v17), while mine is using TLS v1.3. I've not done any configuration on this matter and have low knowledge in infrastructure. He is asking if I could force the TLS to be v1.2, so his enviroment could access my API.
Is this a setting that I should place in my code or is this a setting that I should configure in Heroku?
How test if a TLS v1.2 is accepted by my API?
I've only found ways to check/alter my request to use TLS v1.2, while I need to receive/accept connection using this version.
Thanks in Advance.

Are you using ACM (automated certificate management powered by Let's Encrypt) or Heroku SSL (bring your own cert)? In the latter case, TLS 1.2 should work out of the box. I don't know about ACM though.
